# Are Integration Tests asynchronously (using C# code) in VS2010 when debug code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, testing, integration-testing

I have met the following problem regarding the integration tests.

The code (simple using some other functions). I have put breakpoint on `AddItem` function.

```
[TestInitialize]
      public void MyTestInitialize() {
         Assert.IsTrue( AddItem() );
      }

 [TestCleanup]
      public void MyTestCleanup() {
         Assert.IsTrue( RemoveItem() );
      }

[TestMethod]
public void ListTest(){
   AClass test = new AClass();
   Assert.IsTrue(test.List().Count > 0);
}

private bool AddItem() {
  AClass obj = new AClass();

  Assert.IsTrue(obj.Add("test", "123")); //no duplicate will be allowed ! (return false if duplicate found)

  obj.Files = ConstructFiles();
  ...
  ...
}

private string[] ConstructFiles(){
  return Directory.GetFiles(@"/folder/files", "*.doc"); 
    //when execute the above code then the breakpoint from `AddItem` is reached !!!
}
```

When testing `ListTest` will automatically call `AddItem` (because of `TestInitialize` attribute).

First call is ok but when this function(`AddItem`) call another function `ConstructFiles` then the breakpoint for `AddItem` is reached and execute again the function.

Why ?

Of course, I have another tests using `TestMethod` attribute but something is unclear when call first time `AddItem` and it calls `ConstructFiles`.

Comment: Does your obj.Files setter call AddItem?

Comment: When the breakpoint is reached, look at the call stack and see what it is being called from.  That should give you a clear indication.

Comment: I've already watched the Call Stack and it is called from MyTestInitialize when continuing to test other functions

Comment: Are you using MSTest, NUnit, or...?

Comment: I'm running tests inside Visual Studio (CTRL+R,A), perhaps is about MSTest ...

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, the issue is `return Directory.GetFiles(@"/folder/files", "*.doc"); ` because returns execption: `No file or folder found` or something similar. That's why is `asynchronously` :) Thanks for help anyway